# Synonym request: [camel] and [apache-camel]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camel) and [apache-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-camel) seems related to the open-source [camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

In the detailed description of [camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camel) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/camel/info we can read :

> Use the apache-camel tag. This tag is deprecated and should really be
>   merged/removed.

Some questions have both tags https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camel+apache-camel (17).

Could it be possible to merge this 2 tags, and let only one ?

Comment: Better just to retag (or merge) the camel into it's apache-variant.

Comment: @Deduplicator : I retagged all questions using tag apache-camel (some are still under review). Then the camel tag could be removed ?

Comment: It will cease to exist in a few hours, whn the daily tag-pruning runs.

Comment: I still see both these tags, so perhaps someone created them again ?

Comment: yes, [camel] tag seems back sinc the beginning of 2016, I suggest it to be a synonym for [apache-camel] but there is only 1 vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it would be better for the tags to be merged instead of synonymized.  Synonyms are best left for tags where they *both mean the same thing* in all contexts.

---

The tag excerpt was updated to say

> Use the apache-camel tag. This tag is deprecated and should be removed.

And all of the questions have been re-tagged. So the tag should be automatically cleaned up sometime in the next day.

Comment: FYI, the tag is still there. Also, I don't see the excerpt you quoted anywhere.

Comment: @DavidS that's usually a sign that someone created the tag again.

Comment: Damn them. Oh well.