# Proposed: make [camel] a synonym of [apache-camel]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I think [camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camel) should be a tag synonym of [apache-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-camel).

I see this was [requested back in March](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288493), but at that time the
questions were just manually retagged, and a deprecation message was put
into the excerpt. Naturally, that excerpt disappeared when the tag did.
This did not keep the [camel's nose out of the tent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel%27s_nose); it simply
cropped up again in October. Making it a synonym would seem to be the
only permanent solution.

I have not been able to find any other project named Camel (admittedly,
between Apache Camel, camel case, and the Perl "Camel Book", it's a
difficult search). If some other project named Camel does come along in
the future, we would want to give it a tag name that clearly
distinguishes it from [apache-camel] in any case. We could then add
disambiguation text to both tags.

[apache-camel]: About 4,300 questions, oldest dated 27 Oct 2008, has had
tag info since February 2011.

[camel]: 29 questions, oldest dated 27 Oct 2015 (exactly 7 years later,
funny coincidence). Spot-checking, most seem clearly related to
[apache-camel]; some use both tags, some refer to it in the body.

I don't have any reputation in [apache-camel], so I can't vote for this
myself. I did change the excerpt text in [camel] to encourage people not
to use it, and to vote for the synonym, but so far only one person has
done so.

I would flag it on SO for moderator attention, but I don't see any way
to flag a tag.

Answer (score 7):

A synonym has already been suggested, so...

## [Go Vote For It!](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-camel/synonyms)

If you have a score of 5 or more in the tag (Tag scores), and at least 2500 reputation on the site, you can vote to make it a synonym. Once it reaches a score of 4, it will become a synonym... Yaay!

Comment: Three days later, no votes. I don't see a relevant chat channel. How can we get the attention of these users? Perhaps start fixing the tag in their posts and mention it in the edit note?